# can't remove icon from my taskbar:(

Tags: windows-7

Okay. I have windows 7. 4 days ago, I tried to re-install yahoo messenger. I got an error message; C:\Program Yahoo\Messenger(x86)YahooMessehger. the little smiley character has been installing ever since, and I can't delete it from my taskbar, like I can with other icons. please help me. I don't know if it's corrupted icon:{

Comment: What happens when you unpin it from the taskbar?

Comment: Is the icon in the taskbar or the system tray?

Answer (score 1):

Install [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and search for all occurrences of "yahoo", to see if some part of yahoo messenger is still installed and starts with the computer. If yes, go and delete the file (and maybe its directory), then reboot. To be extra sure, I would only rename it, rather than delete, and wait for a few days to make sure that no harm was done.

Next time when uninstalling an application, use [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/download-freeware-version.php) to ensure that the application was fully uninstalled, without any leftovers.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the taskbar, start task manager, go to processes, kill it. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned how you tried to remove the icon, so I am going out on a limb here:

I am betting that there is no Yahoo Messenger in START >> CONTROL PANEL >> ADD/REMOVE PROGRAMS

You may see a process running under TASK MANAGER and you may be able to END PROCESS and watch the icon disappear.

Go to START >> RUN and type REGEDIT

When the editor opens, navigate to 
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Look for a key for Yahoo Messenger - if found, this is why you are seeing the reinstallation of YM.

Make a backup of the registry and then delete only the key for YM (I don't use it and am unsure of the name you will find here)

DO NOT PROCEED if you do not know if what you are deleting does, in fact, belong to Yahoo Messenger. GOOGLE IT!

That should prevent your reinstallation.

Now go kill the process in TASK MANAGER one more time, if it is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by renaming the icon at:
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\QUick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar